# How to make an engine with application layout like Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to make an engine. My engine may be mountable or not it's not important. But I would like to use my main application layout like Devise for rendering the engine's views. This also very easy.

**But!** When my application's layout and rails engine's view template rendering, I got an exception because I use url helpers in my layout, but this url helpers is in my main_app. So I know I can write a main_app context before all url helpers in layout file but I don't want to do it. 
Devise is working this way. You don't have to write main_app.pages_url in your application layout if you view sessions/new view for example. But I don't know how they do it. I would like to know it and I've read the code I've read the documentation and I found nothing. Please somebody tell me how they do it. How can I make an engine that handle main_app url helpers like Devise. Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb

Comment: No this isn't it. These generate devise helpers in main_app context. I try to use a main application url helper in application layout. In this case my regular rails engine  renders engine view file and the application layout file together do not find url helper methods of mainApp (but with main_app). For example I have an application with a layer and there is a menu in the layer. I use some url helpers in my menu. After it I render an engine view. All my url helper work with main_app.example_path format, but devise not require this annoying context before every MainApp helper.How devise do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of your engine. If your engine contains the line `isolate_namespace SomeModule`, it means that the `url_helpers` (and helpers in general) won't be shared between your application and the engine. So you need to resort to tools like `main_app` and so forth.

That said, all that Devise does to share the layout is to simply not call `isolate_namespace`, which is how engines work since when they were introduced in Rails 2.2. The `isolate_namespace` feature was added on Rails 3.1 for those who wished stronger decoupling.

Comment: I tried before to remove isolate_namespace line from my engine and I rewrote routes.rb to Rails.application.routes, but this engine was generated with --mountable. Now I generate a new engine without mountable option and it Works perfectly. I have no idea what may be the difference. But it works. Thank you!